# How to transform the value to csv after make prediction in flask python

Tags: python, flask, deployment, model, lstm

I m currently working on my own project and I badly need some help regarding this issues as this issues has been stuck me for quite a while, hence I m here to sincere please guide me and share some tips regarding this issues. Thanks n advance and appreciate.

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'StringIO'

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template
import io
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMAResults


app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Let's TRY to Predict..</h1>
                </br>
                </br>
                <p> Insert your CSV file and then download the Result
                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" class="btn btn-block"/>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Predict</button>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"

    
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    #print("file contents: ", file_contents)
    #print(type(file_contents))
    print(csv_input)
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)

    stream.seek(0)
    result = stream.read()
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])

    # load the model from disk
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    dataset = df.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
    dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (dataset.shape[0], 1, dataset.shape[1]))
    df = model.predict(dataset)
    excel_file = df.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(execel_file, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_output = execel_file.getvalue()

        

    response = make_response(trans.to_csv())
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 9000, host = "localhost")
```

Answer (score 0):

To save your prediction, you can first convert your df to real "DataFrame". For example

```py
predict_res = model.predict(dataset)
df_predict = pd.DataFrame(predict_res, columns=["predict"])
df_predict.to_csv("predict.csv", index=False, header=False, encoding='utf8')
```